# Accessing a part of reducer state from one reducer within another reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, reducers

I do not know how to access a boolean `isLoading` flag from `reducerForm.js` reducer in `reducerRegister.js`. I have used `combineReducers()` and I use `isLoading` to disable a button during form submit.

It's initial state is false, after clicking submit, it changes to `true`. After the form submission is successful, `isLoading` is reset to `false` again. Below is the relevant code for this issue:

**actionRegister.js**

```
let _registerUserFailure = (payload) => {
    return {
        type: types.SAVE_USER_FAILURE,
        payload
    };
};
let _registerUserSuccess = (payload) => {
    return {
        type: types.SAVE_USER_SUCCESS,
        payload,
        is_Active: 0,
        isLoading:true
    };
};

let _hideNotification = (payload) => {
    return {
        type: types.HIDE_NOTIFICATION,
        payload: ''
    };
};

// asynchronous helpers
export function registerUser({ // use redux-thunk for asynchronous dispatch
    timezone,
    password,
    passwordConfirmation,
    email,
    name
}) {
    return dispatch => {
        axios.all([axios.post('/auth/signup', {
                    timezone,
                    password,
                    passwordConfirmation,
                    email,
                    name,
                    is_Active: 0
                })
                // axios.post('/send', {email})
            ])
            .then(axios.spread(res => {
                dispatch(_registerUserSuccess(res.data.message));
                dispatch(formReset());
                setTimeout(() => {
                    dispatch(_hideNotification(res.data.message));
                }, 10000);
            }))
            .catch(res => {
                // BE validation and passport error message
                dispatch(_registerUserFailure(res.data.message));
                setTimeout(() => {
                    dispatch(_hideNotification(res.data.message));
                }, 10000);
            });
    };
}
```

**actionForm.js**

```
export function formUpdate(name, value)  {
    return {
        type: types.FORM_UPDATE_VALUE,
        name, //shorthand from name:name introduced in ES2016
        value
    };
}
export function formReset() {
  return {
    type: types.FORM_RESET
  };
}
```

**reducerRegister.js**

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  error:{},
  is_Active:false,
  isLoading:false
};
const reducerSignup = (state = INITIAL_STATE , action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case types.SAVE_USER_SUCCESS:
      return { ...state, is_Active:false, isLoading: true, error: { register: action.payload }};
      case types.SAVE_USER_FAILURE:
      return { ...state, error: { register: action.payload }};
      case types.HIDE_NOTIFICATION:
      return { ...state , error:{} };
   }
      return state;
};
export default reducerSignup;
```

**reducerForm.js**

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
    values: {}
};
const reducerUpdate = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case types.FORM_UPDATE_VALUE:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                values: Object.assign({}, state.values, {
                    [action.name]: action.value,
                })
            });
        case types.FORM_RESET:
        return INITIAL_STATE;
        // here I need isLoading value from reducerRegister.js
    }
    return state;
};
export default reducerUpdate;
```

**reducerCombined.js**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import reducerRegister from './reducerRegister';
import reducerLogin from './reducerLogin';
import reducerForm from './reducerForm';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  signup:reducerRegister,
  signin: reducerLogin,
  form: reducerForm
});

export default rootReducer;
```

This is where I use `isLoading`:

```
  let isLoading = this.props.isLoading;
<FormGroup>
    <Col smOffset={4} sm={8}>
     <Button type="submit"  disabled={isLoading}
       onClick={!isLoading ? isLoading : null}
     >
     { isLoading ? 'Creating...' : 'Create New Account'}
       </Button>
   </Col>
       </FormGroup>
```

Mapping state to props within the same component

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        errorMessage: state.signup.error,
    isLoading: state.signup.isLoading,
    values: state.form.values

    };
}
```

Answer (score 51):

This is covered in the Redux FAQ at https://redux.js.org/faq/reducers#how-do-i-share-state-between-two-reducers-do-i-have-to-use-combinereducers:

> Many users later want to try to share data between two reducers, but find that combineReducers does not allow them to do so. There are several approaches that can be used:
>
> - If a reducer needs to know data from another slice of state, the state tree shape may need to be reorganized so that a single reducer is handling more of the data.
> - You may need to write some custom functions for handling some of these actions. This may require replacing combineReducers with your own top-level reducer function. You can also use a utility such as reduce-reducers to run combineReducers to handle most actions, but also run a more specialized reducer for specific actions that cross state slices.
> - Async action creators such as redux-thunk have access to the entire state through getState(). An action creator can retrieve additional data from the state and put it in an action, so that each reducer has enough information to update its own state slice.

Comment: Thanks, @markerikson, miss that part of doc, will read, but last approach seems best to me with getState()

Comment: So number one says that if `reducer A` will in the end need data from `reducer B` you need to merge them to be `reducer AB`, right?

Comment: As one potential option, yes.

Answer (score 37):

A reducer cannot access another reducer's state, but if you're using [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) you can do so from within an action creator. As an example, you can define an action creator like this:

```
export const someAction = () =>
  (dispatch, getState) => {
    const someVal = getState().someReducer.someVal;
    dispatch({ type: types.SOME_ACTION, valFromOtherReducer: someVal });
  };
```

Answer (score 8):

React Redux works on unidirectional data flow.

```
Action ---> Reducer /store ---> Reducer
```

Reducer works on small subset of store, you can not access store inside reducer which is not part of Reducer. you can either need to fire new action  from the component based on reducer state return.

Comment: how do you access then, I get you can fire an action to send data.