# Access and Changing global state properties inside a reducer in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I want to have just one loader (backdrop and spinner) inside app component and show it when i need (depends on redux state's property called showLoader) in every where of my react application. So I have a global reducer called `appReducer` which is contains showLoader property. the question is how can i change showLoader inside another reducer, `orderReducer` when i need?

for example when dispatch `FETCH_ORDERS_REQUEST` action, showLoader should be true and after that when `FETCH_ORDERS_SUCCESS` action dispatched, showLoader should be false.
How can i do that?
Thank you

Comment: write custom middleware which will be triggered by a list of your action types

Comment: @demkovych ok can you get me an example link? :) thanks...

Comment: you are using axios?

Comment: @demkovych no, i'm inside of microsoft share point and i use it's api which is a promise.

Comment: dig into documentation https://redux.js.org/advanced/middleware

Comment: it should help you solve your problem [Check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42257050/9758658)

Comment: why can't you handle FETCH_ORDERS_REQUEST from appReducer too? unless i didnt understand the problem correctly sorry for that.

Comment: reducer accept multiple case values, just use them

Answer (score 0):

Just use multiple action types in global reducer:

```
switch (type) {
  case FETCH_ORDERS_REQUEST:
  case OTHER_REQUEST:
    return {
      loading: true
    }
  case FETCH_ORDERS_REQUEST_SUCCESS:
  case OTHER_REQUEST_SUCCESS:
    return {
      loading: false
    }

}
```