# adding counter to redux state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to add a like increment count using redux to my app, but I am not what I have to do I have been tampering with it for the last few days and have gotten nowhere. I wanted to use my comments from my shared folder as the state that I wanted to alter on the store. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

this is my store:

```
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { Comments } from './comments';
import { counterReducer } from './counter'

export const ConfigureStore = () => {
const store = createStore(
    combineReducers({
        counter : counterReducer,
        comments: Comments
    }
));

return store;
};
```

action creators:

```
import * as ActionTypes from './ActionTypes';

export const addComment = (commentId, author, text, likes, date) => ({
type: ActionTypes.ADD_COMMENT,
payload: {
    commentId : commentId,
    author: author,
    text: text,
    likes: likes,
    date: date
}
});

export const likeComment = (commentId, likes) => ({
type: ActionTypes.LIKE_COMMENT,
payload: {
    commentId: commentId,
    likes: likes
}
 });
```

my counter reducer for the likes (i am using my COMMENTS as my state that has the commentId, comments, author, dates, likes):

```
import * as ActionTypes from './ActionTypes';
import { COMMENTS } from '../shared/comments';


export const counterReducer = (state = COMMENTS, action) => {
switch(action.type) {
    case ActionTypes.LIKE_COMMENT:
        const comment = action.payload
        comment.id = state.length 
        comment.like = state.likes + 1
        return state.concat(comment)
    default:
        return state;
}
};
```

This is the main component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import TopComment from './TopComment';
import DisplayComment from './PostComment';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { addComment, likeComment } from '../redux/ActionCreators';

const mapStateToProps = state => {
return {
    comments: state.comments,
    likes: state.likes
}
};

const mapDispatchToProps = {
addComment: (commentId, author, text, likes, date) => (addComment(commentId, author, text, 
likes, date)),
likeComment: (likes) => (likeComment(likes))
  }

class Main extends Component{
render(){
    return(
        <div className="comment-box">
            <h1>Join the discussion!</h1>
            <h1>Adam's post:</h1>
            <TopComment/>
            <DisplayComment
            addComment = {this.props.addComment}
            likeComment ={this.props.likeComment}
            comments = {this.props.comments}
            />
        </div>
    )
   }
   }

   export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Main));
```

post comment component that will add and display each comment that has been entered
through the input:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button, Card, CardBody, CardTitle, CardText } from 'reactstrap';
import { Control, LocalForm, Errors} from 'react-redux-form';

// will check validation
const required = val => val && val.length;
const maxLength = len => val => !val || (val.length <= len);
const minLength = len => val => val && (val.length >= len);



// will display comment when posted
function RenderComments({comments}) {

 function handleLike(){
    this.props.likeComment(this.props.likeComment)
 }

 if (comments) {
    return (
        <div className="col-sm-12">
            <h4>Comments</h4>
                {
                    comments.map(comment => {
                        return (
                            <div className="container">
                            <div className="row">
                                <div className="col-sm-12 ">
                                    <Card style={{ 
                                        backgroundColor: '#212d40',
                                        borderColor: '#fff',
                                        borderRadius: '0.25rem',
                                        padding: '0.5rem 0.5rem 0.5rem',
                                        marginBottom: '20px'
                                        }}>
                                        <CardBody>
                                            <img src="./images/random.jpeg" alt="random" height="50px" />
                                            <CardTitle tag="h3">{comment.author}</CardTitle>
                                            <CardText>{comment.text}, <br/>
                                            likes: {comment.likes} <br/>
                                            {new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', { year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day: '2-digit'}).format(new Date(Date.parse(comment.date)))}
                                            </CardText> <br/>
                                            <Button onClick={handleLike}>Like </Button>
                                        </CardBody>
                                    </Card>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        );
                    })
                }
        </div>
    );
}
return <div/>;
}

class PostComment extends Component {

handleSubmit(values) {
    this.props.addComment(this.props.commentId, values.author, values.text, values.date);
}

render(){
    return(
        <div>
            <LocalForm className="comment-form" onSubmit={ values => 
      this.handleSubmit(values) }>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <Control.text
                    model=".author"
                    className="form-control" 
                    placeholder="name" 
                    validators={{
                        required, 
                        minLength: minLength(2),
                        maxLength: maxLength(15)
                    }}
                    />
                    <Errors
                    className="text-danger"
                    model=".author"
                    show="touched"
                    component="div"
                    messages={{
                        required: 'Required',
                        minLength: 'Must be at least 2 characters',
                        maxLength: 'Must be 15 characters or less'
                    }}
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <Control.text
                    model=".text"
                    className="form-control"
                    placeholder="comment" 
                    />
                </div>
                <Button className="btn-color"  color="primary" type="submit">Submit</Button>
            </LocalForm>
        </div>
    )
}
}

function DisplayComment(props){
 return(
    <div>
        <div className="col">
        <RenderComments 
        addComment = {props.addComment}
        deleteComment =  {props.deleteComment}
        comments = {props.comments}
        likeComment = {props.likeComment}
        />
        </div>
        <div className="col">
        <PostComment
        addComment = {props.addComment}
        comments = {props.comments}
        likeComment= {props.likeComment}
        />
        </div>
    </div>
  )
  }

   export default DisplayComment
```

this is my commments from my shared file that has all the comment data (likes, comment, date, etc):

```
export const COMMENTS = [
{
    commentId: 0,
    author: 'Richard',
    text: 'I love disum!',
    likes: 1,
    date: "2020-07-01T19:44Z"
},
{
    commentId: 1,
    author: 'Jake Paul',
    text: 'Fried foods are the best!',
    likes:  0,
    date: "2020-09-20T19:44Z"
}
]
```

Comment: Step 1 - install and configure [redux dev tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd?hl=en)

Comment: `comment.like = state.likes + 1` looks weird... where is like count actually stored, in each comment or one count for all comments?

Comment: @DimaTisnek I was looking store the likes for each comment. Can that be done on redux?

Comment: @dmarceo316 - as pointed out in my answer, but putting the `likes` count in each comment entity, your confusing the source of truth for the number of likes on a given comment. What do you want to do - just store the number of likes? Or store meta information about a like - when it was created, who it was created by, etc? If you want to store meta information about a like, then get rid of the `likes` property of your comment object.

Comment: Ahh now I see what you were trying to do. **Bye default**, the two combined reducers are **independent**, one reducer cannot see the state in the other reducer. But you are trying to peek at the other reducer. There's a way to do that, if you really need it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing a part of reducer state from one reducer within another reducer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42239302/accessing-a-part-of-reducer-state-from-one-reducer-within-another-reducer)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42239302/accessing-a-part-of-reducer-state-from-one-reducer-within-another-reducer

Comment: @Adam I was looking to start each comment off with 0, But I was only looking to increment an individual comment likes. I'm hoping that makes sense. I am a little new to redux and trying to piece everything together.

Comment: @dmarceo316 - If you have a counter reducer where you store all your likes, then a comment's likes are [derived data](https://redux.js.org/recipes/computing-derived-data). A comment only has likes it there are entries in the likes reducer, otherwise, it has zero likes. Alternatively, as I illustrated in my answer below, you can just store everything together and modify your `comments` reducer to increment the number of likes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing the source of truth for comment likes. Should the likes count be part of the comment? Or should it be it's own thing?

Let's [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) and just keep the likes count as part of the comment as you have already set up - get rid of your other counter reducer altogether.

Your comments reducer should now look like this:

```js
  switch(action.type) {
    case ActionTypes.ADD_COMMENT:
        // your existing code to handle adding a comment to your state

    // this new case increments the likes for a given comment
    case ActionTypes.LIKE_COMMENT:
        return state.comments.map(c => c.commentId === action.payload.commentId ? ({ ...c,likes: c.likes+1 }) : c);
    default:
        return state;
  }
};
```